# Publishing failed at transporting phase in SDL Tridion Sites 9 setup with UDP Microservices setup in HTTPS

Tags: publishing, transport, sites-9, https

We set it up SDL Tridion Sites 9.0 Content Delivery UDP microservices for **HTTPS** with keystore file, Publishing failed at transporting phase

**CM Transport cd_core Logs:** D:\Tridion\bin\logs\cd_core.2019-02-01.log

```
2019-02-01 18:04:21,960 ERROR [Thread-0] BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute retrieveFileIfPresent on destination: https://xxxudpapi.xxxx.com:8084/httpupload due to: org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException. MaxRetries exceeded.
org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: https protocol is not supported
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:109)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.lambda$retrieveFileIfPresent$1(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:301)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.runWithRetry(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:529)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:297)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.retrieveFileIfPresent(TransportPoolConnector.java:78)
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:51)
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.EndpointMetaWorker.getMetadata(EndpointMetaWorker.java:33)
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.<init>(DestinationController.java:112)
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerFactory.getDestinationController(DestinationControllerFactory.java:43)
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.createOrLoadTransaction(TransactionProcessor.java:166)
    at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.TransactionProcessor.<init>(TransactionProcessor.java:73)
    at com.tridion.transport.TransportService.handleTransaction(TransportService.java:246)
2019-02-01 18:04:36,123 ERROR [pool(transportConnectorPool)-4-thread-1] BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute list on destination: https://xxxudpapi.xxxx.com:8084/httpupload due to: org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException. MaxRetries exceeded.
org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: https protocol is not supported
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:109)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.lambda$list$3(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:410)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.runWithRetry(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:529)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.list(BaseHTTPSTransportConnector.java:406)
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.list(TransportPoolConnector.java:74)
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.DestinationProgressWorker.call(DestinationProgressWorker.java:59)
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerSlotChecker.call(DestinationControllerSlotChecker.java:58)
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationControllerSlotChecker.call(DestinationControllerSlotChecker.java:19)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform HTTPS uploads (it's necessary for HTTPS Discovery Service Transport) the Transport Service, Refer to the documentation for [Importing a certificate for publishing over HTTPS](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-60D158FC-CDBE-48B8-A011-8699740549B1)

We created the new Keystore file with certificate import and configured as mentioned in the documentation and issue has been fixed and publishing working fine.

**cd_transport_config.xml**

```
<Sender Type="DiscoveryService" Class="com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.DiscoveryServiceTransportConnector">
    <KeyStore Path="d:\keystore\cacerts" Secret="xx" />  
</Sender>
```